# try to fill a 2d array but it remains a 1d array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to fill a simple 2d array, but when I test the code it shows up as a 1d array with as many elements of my desired 2d array.

```
void clearBoard(int row, int col) 
{
    int grid[row][col];
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col;j++) {
                grid[i][j] = 0;
                cout << grid[i][j] << " ";

            }
        }   cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int row1 = 2;
    int col1 = 2;
    //int _row = atoi(argv[0]);
    //int _col = atoi(argv[2]);
    //int _grid[5][5];
    //setBoard(row, col);

    //cout << "enter the size of the board:";
    //cin >> _row >> _col;
    clearBoard(row1, col1);
```

This is the output:

> 0 0 0 0

I'm to get as my output:

```
0 0 
0 0
```

As you can see I commented out

```
int _row = atoi(argv[0]);
int _col = atoi(argv[2]);

cin >> _row >> _col;
```

Is the right way to get any size array?

Thanks guys.

Comment: I don't think C++ allows you to declare an array with dynamic size like that. That's a C99 feature.

Comment: @Barmar yup, technically new operator or some other standardized solution should be used but the correct answer has been posted by Joe.

Comment: Aha! The messed up formatting confused me. It looked like the `cout << endl` was inside the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `cout << endl;` into your for loop (it is actually out of both of them) as it is currently going to print all the results without a new line unless you move it into the main for loop.:

NOTE: as the arrays in C++ must have a constant size, `int grid[row][col]` won't work as row and col are parameters which are not constant.

```
void clearBoard(int row, int col) 
{
    int grid[row][col]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < col;j++) 
        { 
            grid[i][j] = 0; cout << grid[i][j] << " ";     
        } 
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

A fix for the constant size error would be to use a `std::vector<std::pair<int, int> >` instead, although that would require some reworking.

Comment: note: `int grid[row][col]` is illegal in standard C++:

Comment: @Matt McNabb - crikey! I nearly would have forgotten that had you not told me. Thanks:)

Comment: really appreciate the quick responses, the endl was the problem. For the parameters, can I just make them const? I ran it w/o it and it worked fine, but I'm worried it's going to give me problems later on.

Comment: @Jeremy78 - you cannot put the parameters as const as it still won't accept it. However, you could set a const global variable for both the row and column size if you wanted. However, if not, the best way is to use a vector of pairs or your own row/column struct/class that emulates the behaviour if you want:)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are printing the `endl` after the outer loop.

Simply change it to:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col;j++) {
                grid[i][j] = 0;
                cout << grid[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;  //Print newline after printing a row
        }
```

> Is the right way to get any size array?

Unlike Java where you can declare the array size during runtime. In C++, if you want to set the array size, the size must be a constant.

You can do this:

```
const int rows = 5;
const int cols = 5;
```